# dijkstra implememtation giving wrong outputs

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

i am trying to solve a problem for my understanding of dijkstra algorithm .this is the mentioned problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dijkstrashortreach  .  only the first testcase is accepted all others are wrong.please anyone hint me what could be wrong with my implementation . as far as i understand the algorithm i have implemented it correctly

Here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100001
#define INF INT_MAX
#define pii pair< int, int >
#define pb(x) push_back(x)

int main() {
int i, u, v, w, sz, nodes, edges, starting;
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    priority_queue< pii, vector< pii >, greater< pii >  > Q;
    vector< pii > G[MAX];
    int D[MAX];
    bool F[MAX];
    // create graph
    scanf("%d %d", &nodes, &edges);
    for(i=0; i<edges; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d %d", &u, &v, &w);
        G[u].pb(pii(v, w));
        G[v].pb(pii(u, w)); // for undirected
    }
    scanf("%d", &starting);
    // initialize distance vector
    for(i=1; i<=nodes; i++) { D[i] = INF; F[u] = 0;}
    D[starting] = 0;
    Q.push(pii(starting, 0));
    // dijkstra
    while(!Q.empty()) {
        u = Q.top().first;
        Q.pop();
        if(F[u]) continue;
        sz = G[u].size();
        for(i=0; i<sz; i++) {
            v = G[u][i].first;
            w = G[u][i].second;
            if(!F[v] && D[u]+w < D[v]) {
                    D[v] = D[u] + w;
                    Q.push(pii(v, D[v]));
            }
        }
        F[u] = 1; // done with u
    }
// result
    for(i=1; i<=nodes; i++){
        if(i!=starting){
        if(D[i]==INF)printf("%d ",-1);
        printf("%d ",D[i]);
    }
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better place for your question is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PravarJawalekar Coming from someone who has also said that before, code review is only for code that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your min heap is not correct, you need to define comparison function for your pair. Using `greater` is not enough.

This is the comparison C++ using for `pair`,

```
template <class T1, class T2>
  bool operator<  (const pair<T1,T2>& lhs, const pair<T1,T2>& rhs)
{ return lhs.first<rhs.first || (!(rhs.first<lhs.first) && lhs.second<rhs.second); }
```

You can see that, it always compares `first` then `second`, but your ideal behavior should be compared `second` before `first` (as in your case, first is the node id, and second is its weight). For more details, please look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/operators/)

Or, you can just reverse position of `first` and `second` in your pair.

One more problem is

```
for(i=1; i<=nodes; i++) { D[i] = INF; F[u] = 0;}
```

Should be:

```
for(i=1; i<=nodes; i++) { D[i] = INF; F[i] = 0;}
```

Last problem is, for each new test case, you need to print the result in a **new line**, plus, your last if condition is not correct. It should be:

```
for(i=1; i<=nodes; i++){
    if(i!=starting){
        if(D[i]==INF)
            cout << -1 << " ";
        else    
            cout << D[i] << " ";
    }
}
cout << endl;
```

My [code](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dijkstrashortreach/submissions/code/18131220) has been accepted after all those changes.

Comment: please explain or give a little hint to why is that incorrect

Comment: i used this comparator 

`struct comp {
bool operator() (const pii &a, const pii &b) {
return a.second > b.second;
}
};`
But only one more testcase got correct rest are wrong :(

Comment: @kshitijsingh see my updates, my code has been accepted after those changes.

Comment: thanks a lot for trying that out for me but that code is not visible to me.can you paste it somewhere else like pastebin so that i can see it.

Comment: @kshitijsingh it is your code plus the above `for` loop. Nothing else, just try, and if it not works, tell me, I will give you the code.

Comment: i tried with loop modified and added comparator as you said but only two are getting correct :(

Comment: @kshitijsingh http://ideone.com/AECGxZ. Strange, actually, it is better to post your code. You need to work more to polish your C++ skill :)

Comment: Thanks alot for the advice :) i am trying that.